# What happens when I unregister and reregister a dataset with Phonograph?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

Some kinds of schema changes require reregistering in Phonograph. What are the implications of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Unregistration is a dangerous operation. Some of the implications of this are:

1. Edits made to that Table are lost. If edits need to be retained, it is possible to first download all the edits before unregistration, then after reregistration post them all back again to retain the edits history.
2. The `TableRid` changes. Often, queries in Slate dashboards reference the `TableRid`, so they may stop working.
3. The Table will not be searchable until a reindex has finished following reregistration.